# woocommerce theme development without shortcodes

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, shortcode

I was wondering if someone could help me out. I am developing a theme that uses woocommerce as the ecommerce solution. I know that there are predefined shortcodes that you can use but i was wondering if there was a way to actually implement woocommerce items in my php code as opposed to using shortcodes.

Thanks,

Comment: yes. read the manual.

Comment: Well I'm stumped, have you found this in the docs anywhere?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:
https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/125286/60175

```
<?php echo do_shortcode('[product_page id="31"]'); ?>
```

And at the Shortcodes doc, I see

> To find the Product ID, go to the Product > Edit screen and look in the URL for the postid= as shown below.

http://docs.woothemes.com/document/woocommerce-shortcodes/

Of course this still uses shortcodes (pretty slick), but in your PHP. The Wordpress framework must be available in your PHP page, which I think you do by including wp-load.php at the beginning.

Comment: @har Great, glad to hear it. Could you vote this your answer?